# Clients website in his own domain like tumblr

Tags: php, cross-domain

I have a website with products and my clients have it also but in their subdomain, for example: myclientname.example.com

And now question:

He wants to show this website (myclientname.example.com) in his own domain.
I have seen this in tubmlr blog i think. You can show your blog in your domain but it is still hosted by tumblr.
I am using php 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect myclientname.example.com to a link with header location, but the url will change.

Then, you can use an iframe of 100% * 100% to "include" the full website inside your page, with the same URL (always myclientname.example.com but you see the website inside the iframe).

I don"t know if exists better solutions.

Comment: Yeah but for example tumblr can do it in some way. Have you got any idea how is it done?